# ubuntu 18 stucks to purple screen after update

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, lvm, live-cd

Some days ago I run a simple update, then my computer chrashes. When I start it, after some seconds, I just see a purple screen and nothing happens.

1. I can't go on recovery mode by holding `shift` nor `esc`.
2. From Live CD I can't mount the partition where Ubuntu 18.04 is installed (read below)

From Live CD I run

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ blkid
 /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
 /dev/sda1: UUID="ABDB-0A93" TYPE="vfat" 
 /dev/sda2: UUID="o9H0is-5d5M-h42G-FwCG-QbpK-brc8-0y511X" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
 /dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" 
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="17164613-461c-494b-9c12-b6f82a487ed9" TYPE="ext4" 
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="a124fd2f-318c-487e-9b7e-b576037f3b9f" TYPE="swap"
```

(Since `fdisk` doesn't work properly on GUID Partition Table it doesn't list `sda2` partition).

I can see the partition in Nautilus, but if I clik on it appears the message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

So I try

```
dmesg | tail
[ 7588.001413] ath: regdomain 0x817c dynamically updated by country IE
[ 7588.001435] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IT
[ 7588.001436] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 7588.001438] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 7588.001440] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 7588.001441] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 7588.001443] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
[ 7588.001445] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 7880.935634] JBD2: Unrecognised features on journal
[ 7880.935657] EXT4-fs (dm-0): error loading journal
```

However, if I try to mount `sda2` via shell I get

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/part
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

Since I can't mount sda2 I can't update the grub or see what are the used Kernel. How can I proceed?